# C# Entity Framework tables doesn't show after I include them in code-first from database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado

Normally it should add 3 tables, but only 2 tables shows up

[image]

```
namespace controle_Bibliothèque
{
    public partial class Modelv6 : DbContext
    {
        public Modelv6()
            : base("name=Modelv6")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<emprunts> emprunts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ouvrages> ouvrages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ouvrages>()
                .Property(e => e.titOUV)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ouvrages>()
                .Property(e => e.nomOUV)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ouvrages>()
                .Property(e => e.typOUV)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ouvrages>()
                .Property(e => e.nomeDIT)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ouvrages>()
                .Property(e => e.disponible)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that the PRIMARY KEY is set on the table.

Comment: I can only see two entities in DbSet. emprunts and  ouvrages wheres the third one? In code first approach, all entities in dbset transform to a table in the database